# Added New Column to Database and Update My Model But I want to Update already existing rows because new Column is Added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

Added New Column to Database and Update My Model But I want to Update already existing rows because new Column is Added.

```
id|Name City
1 |A   |Null
2 |B   |Null
3 |C   |Null
```

I want to Set this City Column Programmetically It is work fine for new entries add For Example if Create View Render it sets the City Column but i want to set it for all ready existing rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are using automatic migrations:**

You can use `[DefaultValue]` attribute when you adding new field.

Or:

You can run update **SQL-script**:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET City='SomeDefaultValue'
WHERE City = NULL;
```

**If you are using custom code-based migrations:**

When you creating migration for your database, you will got something like:

```
 public override void Up()
 {
     AddColumn("dbo.someTable", "City", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "SomeDefaultValue"));    
 }
```

In action parameter you have one of the options: `defaultValue`, this value will be used for all existing rows.

**May be useful:**

[**DefaultValueAttribute Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

[**Code-based Migrations**](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

[**Entity Framework Code First: Migrations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

[**Automatic Code First Migrations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @U10 ...
I done it with other approach in my case we are going with DB first approach i use Linq to Update Column and Save Obj if Value is Null..